# Weka Snowball not working

Tags: java, weka, snowball

I'm trying to create an Italian text classifier with Weka using Weka's `StringToWordVector` to create the features.

The classifier works fine, but I set a stemmer as an option of the filter and it doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
SnowballStemmer sb=new SnowballStemmer();
snowball.setStemmer("italian");

StringToWordVector str2Words = new StringToWordVector();
String[] options_wordVector = { /*other options*/};
str2Words.setOptions(options_wordVector); 
str2Words.setStemmer(sb);
```

When I start debugging in the console log appears

```
Stemmer 'italian' unknown!
```

I tried `sb.stem(string)` too, but the same message appears and the result string is the starting one.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I misunderstood [Weka's stemmers docs](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Stemmers): in `weka.jar` it exists the `weka.core.stemmers package`, but it contains only the wrapper class.

> The Snowball classes are not included, they **only have to be present
>   in the classpath**. The reason for this is, that the Weka team doesn't
>   have to watch out for new versions of the stemmers and update them.

The code in the question actually works after including the stemmers in the classpath.